# Add roles to discord member when they join

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have an issue with give member a role/rank when they are joining my discord, I have just various code statments and none of them has help me so far. Some of the the code that i tried is from Stackoverflow.

my last try is this:

```
client.on('GuildMemberAdd', member => {
    console.log('User: ' + member.user.username + ' has joined the server!');
    var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === "<My role ID>");
    member.roles.add(role);
});
```

This is what I get out of the discord.js documentation and from google when I brows around for a solution for my problem.

I do not know if the problem is that it can not read the `role.id` and it has to be the name.
The issue is just that the ID is a better solution then `role.name`, just in case the name on the role should be changed, since the ID is bound to that role with out dependency to the name of the role.

I do hope that someone can help me out with this issue.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have the same role id across multiple guilds, though you can have the same role names.

Trying to use the ID instead means it's locked to one and specific ID.

Say, the ID belongs to your guild, and the member that joined wasn't joining your server, but someone else's, then `role` would return undefined as the role of the role ID doesn't exist.

If you're using this only for your server, then this should work, just make sure to check that the member joined `your` server. So, other than your server it would use the names instead

```js
client.on('GuildMemberAdd', member => {
    if (member.guild.id === "<My guild ID>") {
    // <My guild ID> represents an ID of a guild that has a role with the ID <My role ID>
        console.log('User: ' + member.user.username + ' has joined the server!');
        var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === "<My role ID>");
        member.roles.add(role);
    } else {
        console.log('User: ' + member.user.username + ' has joined ' + member.guild.name + ' server!');
        var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "<Whatever>");
        member.roles.add(role);
    }
});
```

---

If you want them to be able to save different IDs for each guild, then I suggest you learn how databases work and try to work on them accordingly.

Comment: I do know how a database works, but I am just trying to get some hardcoding to work before putting the database on

Comment: You mean you want to know how to do it with a database? Which database are you using?

Comment: No, I mean that I need to get my hardcoding to work before I put my database on. If I can't get the hardcoding to work then it does not matter what kind of data that I need from the datbase to get it to work

Comment: Oh, use your code, it works, but make sure the role id is pulled from the database that was set up so it works, and if it doesn't exist then look for the names instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to directly add the role using the id:

```
client.on('GuildMemberAdd', member => {
    console.log('User: ' + member.user.username + ' has joined the server!');
    member.roles.add(ROLE_ID);
});
```

Comment: That's not the issue here.